# A RESTful container contains many things. But how to know how to interact with it and what is contained in it?

Tags: rest, uri, rdf, linked-data, fedora-commons

What I meant was: How do we know what requests a particular URI of the container accepts and what parameters we can use?

For example:
the container URI: http://example.com/containers/container1

-> Now I want to know a way to access the metadata of the container. How do I do it?

The main reason I am trying to ask this question is I am working on migration of Fedora Commons from 3 to 4. And I am confused by many different schemas and notations. In some places, they use `http://something.com/smthng/fcr:metadata`.
At some places, they use `http://something.com/smthng/metadata`. Sometimes, fedora namespace will work in the URI and in some places it won't work. I am confused.

I want to know a way to know to all the accepted conventions on a URI.

Comment: How are you using the data?  SPARQL?  Parsing the text serialization?  That could help narrow down where your struggles are.

Comment: Hi, I have used SPARQL till now, only to update the URI content with more properties, like indexing. What is text serialization? The struggle is the migration. The concepts are so new to me and confusing. But for the last week, I have made some progress. But still there is some confusion, particularly in identifying which methods I can use to do find something related to a container. I am the administrator and I can access all the schema files. So, how can I find these details. That I don't understand. The fedora documentation is not good enough.

Comment: So the question is actually about how to use Linked Data Platform, is that correct?

Comment: I am not sure of the terminology? But as what I heard about LDP, I think so. I am getting something. At the same time, I am confused.

Comment: Yea, see the edits to the answer.  Fedora 4 is using LDP as its RDF interface.

Comment: Please consider adding the [tag:linked-data-platform] tag.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think you have to go beyond Wikipedia's [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) definition to understand the standards for URIs, URLs and URNs.

However, the question is more likely about the Linked Data Platform.  If you go to [Concept Mapping - Fedora 3 to 4](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/FEDORA45/Concept+Mapping+-+Fedora+3+to+4) , the links for Fedora 4 go to the  [W3C Linked Data Platform (LDP)](https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp/) recommendation.  That basically states how the REST API works to query RDF data.

LDP containers are a way to partition RDF data so you can query the container and get a list of RDF resources.  I don't think there is a way to query their metadata.  The set of available containers defined in the data itself, and are not required.  I.e. the data may be entirely defined with resources and containers are just a way to partition RDF data.  If you have SPARQL access to the data, one idea is to query the data looking for LDP containers.  Then you can sent REST requests to get that data.

(BTW, A RDF text serialization is a text-based representation of RDF graphs.  Using a text serialization allows users to exchange data in a standard format.  RDF standards include RDF/XML, Turtle, N-Triples, and JSON-LD.)

Comment: Hi, yes I have understood the concepts of URIs,URLs and URNs. I only wonder if there are methods to find out what methods are accepted at particular URI, other than digging out or trial and error methods...but now I realize that the only way is to read the schema if you are an administrator. If you are not the administrator, then you don't need to know. If the URI wish to show something, it will find it's way. This is what I understood as  far.

Comment: Hi, here is my exact confustion:

Comment: localhost/fedora/rest/testcontainer/fcr:metadata is opening metadata content.....but localhost/fedora/rest/testcontainer/fcr:content says prefix fcr is not registered....then how & why fcr:metadata is working?